# Need some explanation with CSS font declaration

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I have this font declaration:

```
font: 700 16px/36px HelveticaNeue,Roboto,sans-serif;
```

But if I want to specify each value separately I can to this:

```
font-weight:700;
font-family: HelveticaNeue,Roboto,sans-serif;
```

But how to separately value `16px/36px` specify in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS property you are looking for is `line-height`, so to properly replicate the shorthand with separate values you would do the following:

```
font-weight:700;
font-size:16px;
line-height:36px;
font-family: HelveticaNeue,Roboto,sans-serif;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
font-size:16px;
line-height:36px;
```